# Changing Magento database

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I have installed magento 1.7 with the database name magento1.7 and now I want to replace this with current live dump with the name magento.

I have changed dbnames in local.xml and config.xml,cleared cache and other things in magento. But now I am getting the below error when i load my magento local.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '921923' for key 'PRIMARY'

Trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(174): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor_inf...', Array)
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(108): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(463): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#18 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

I searched in the log tables for the value "921923" but couldn't able to find any match. Can someone help/guide me to resolve this issue?

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; this then import

Comment: @Jinesh There are 640 tables, In which table i need to put this and import ? I couldn't able to find the table name which is causing this error.

Comment: delete all value in log_visitor_inf.. tables then its run your webstite

Comment: @Jinesh Sure, Will try and post here,Thanks a lot for the swift response.

Comment: If it works let me know

Comment: @Jinesh Thanks a lot, now I could able to load the page, but Css/js are not loading. it is loading as a simple html file. How can I overcome this ?

Comment: check my answer and if it is works then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

this then import and delete all value in log_visitor_inf.. tables then its run your website. Delete this folder var then check the website.